# Extension of a Blaschke Product to the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{a_n\}=1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and the corresponding Blaschke product defined as:

$$B(z)=\prod_n \frac{|a_n|}{a_n} \left( \frac{a_n -z}{1- \overline{a_n}z}\right)$$

Can we find an open subset $\Omega $ such that $\overline{D}(0,1) \subset \Omega$ and a function $f(z) \in \mathcal{H}(\Omega)$, with $f(z)\big|_{D(0,1)}=B(z)$ ?

I really have no idea of how to do this any hints?

Comment: Hmmm ... lots of zeros of $B$ piling up at $1.$

Comment: So we have a negative answer because of the identity theorem? If there were an analytic continuation  we have a dense subset of $\overline{D}(0,1)$ in which the extension of $B$ equals 0 so $B(z)$ should be zero hence contradiction.

Comment: I said dense sorry! I mean with an accumulation point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not even matter where the zeros are: no infinite Blaschke product has holomorphic extension to a domain containing the closed unit disk.

Indeed, since the zeros of a holomorphic function (that is not identically zero) cannot have an interior point of accumulation, any compact subset of the domain contains finitely many zeroes.